# Add values to input fields in the same row

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table which have multiple rows with input fields having same names

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type=text name=icode[] id=icode>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type=text name=description[] id=description>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type=text name=rprice[] id=rprice>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type=text name=discount[] id=discount>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type=text name=fprice[] id=fprice>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now using on focusout function I want to populate the value of description and rprice from the database. But I am unable to do it for the same row. While browsing around I found this piece of code

```
 $(_this).parents('tr').find('#description').val(obj.description);
```

but it updates for all the rows and the specific row.

So basically when i type 1 in icode on row 2, I want description and rprice of row 2 to be updated only not all rows.

I have posted a sample code for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/nA7RL/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `_this` here ..in jquery it should like `$(this)`

Comment: $(This) wont work inside the ajax function therefore i have defined var _this = $this earlier so that i can use it inside the ajax function

Comment: Can you specify the call where you are using this jquery code? There are some confusion in determining what `$(_this)` actually means.

Comment: Ok well i am using $("#icode").live("focusout",function() { }); does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parent instead of parents:

```
$(_this).parent().parent('tr').find('#description').val(obj.description);
```

from jquery: http://api.jquery.com/parents/

The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

In your case, the parents method is going to the higher level tr, and from there, the find method is locating all the existing description fields.

Comment: Edited the answer. did not consider `td` tag before.

Comment: I have posted link to jsfiddle.net for your reference

Answer (score 0):

The `ID` of an element must be unique. If you have duplicate IDs they will not work. Use `class` instead.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="icode[]" class="icode">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="description[]" class="description">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="rprice[]" class="rprice">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="discount[]" class="discount">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fprice[]" class="fprice">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="icode[]" class="icode">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="description[]" class="description">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="rprice[]" class="rprice">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="discount[]" class="discount">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fprice[]" class="fprice">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
​
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.icode').on('change', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('.description').val($(this).val());
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hqqSk/)**

Comment: I am starting to believe it could have something to do with the way I am adding rows. i tried doing the same with id and it worked when I do it the way you have illustrated. But when i dynamically add rows it doesn't work. Can you please look at the following link to see what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/nA7RL/

Comment: Well the problem you are having in your fiddle is one character. If you call `.parents('tr')` instead of `.parent('tr')` then your function will work: http://jsfiddle.net/nA7RL/1/. However there are several other problems in your code, such as `exit;` throws and error and should not be there, your tag attributes should all have `""` quotes around the values, you should not be repeating IDs but use classes instead, etc.

Comment: @SaadBashir - Here is your code cleaned up and fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/nA7RL/2/. Please keep in mind the points I made. This is not just about getting your code to work, it's about getting your code to work properly.